# Starting/Stop Couchbase Server on CentOS 6.6 failing

Tags: couchbase, centos6

I have couchbase version 2.2.0 installed on 6.7 and it worked fine.
But when i changed the centos version from 6.7 to 6.6, couchbase is not starting at all.

Is couchbase having problem with centos 6.6? Noticed some issues at https://issues.couchbase.com/browse/MB-12536 and https://issues.couchbase.com/browse/MB-12849

But could not get the solution with centos 6.6.

If anybody faced the issue, would be helpful if you could let me know how make couchbase 2.2.0 with centos 6.6

```
 [root@localhost ~]# service couchbase-server start
 Starting couchbase-server/usr/bin/dirname: extra operand `2>&1.pid'
 Try `/usr/bin/dirname --help' for more information.
                                                       [  OK  ]

[root@localhost ~]# service couchbase-server restart
Stopping couchbase-serverNOTE: shutdown failed
{badrpc,nodedown}

 Starting couchbase-server/usr/bin/dirname: extra operand `2>&1.pid'
 Try `/usr/bin/dirname --help' for more information.                                                              [  OK  ]
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the following will solve your problem. Edit your couchbase-server file in /etc/init.d as follows. Change:

```
daemon --user couchbase "$DAEMON -- -noinput -detached > /opt/couchbase/var/lib/couchbase/logs/start.log 2>&1"
```

to:

```
daemon --user couchbase "$DAEMON" -- -noinput -detached > /opt/couchbase/var/lib/couchbase/logs/start.log 2>&1
```

I.e. don't surround the whole command with quotes just the DAEMON env var. Also change:

```
daemon "$DAEMON: -k"
```

to:

```
daemon "$DAEMON" -k
```

so it stops right too. That should do it. Let me know if not.